# neural network confusion matrix in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I trained a NN model using the neuralnet package in R to predict 3 classes(y1,y2 and y3) from 6 inputs(x1,x2,..x6). How can I construct a confusion matrix in R for the result of the test? Below are the predicted and actual values

```
library(neuralnet)

nn <- neuralnet(y1+y2+y3 ~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6,
         data=traindata, hidden=5,act.fct = "tanh",linear.output=FALSE)
compute(nn, testdata)$net.result


 $net.result
 1.00000000000  -1.0000000000  -1.0000000000
 1.00000000000  -0.8899999991  -1.0000000000
 0.88898961216  -1.0000000000  -1.0000000000
-1.00000000000  -0.9999981122   0.9993868320

 #actual
 1      -1     -1
 1      -1     -1
-1       1     -1
 1      -1     -1
```

Comment: I only see two classes. Anyway, you can use `table(actual, predicted)`.